# Auto save system for a simple city building game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a city building game by Unity3D, want to design and implement an auto-save system.

The game is like this.

- I have to save both structures and people.
- The map is large and there are A LOT of people, may be more than 1 million!.
- People are not all the same. They have their own role, like worker, boss, bartender, kindergartener.
- People doesn't interact with each other, they only interact with structure (join into the structure). To keep the game simple, I will animate "chit chat sound text effect" over a cafe or a bar instead of having people chatting on the road.
- People only have 2 state: inside a structure, walking on the street.
- People can change their role after come in and out from a structure. It is like they graduate from a school after... 1 minute.
- People density of every place are not the same. There may have roads with only 1 person but other roads with full of people. People stuck on the road will not able to come to the destination on time.
- We can see people walk on street all the time. No day no night no sleep no rest. Simple routine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrubp.png

What I did

- Save all structures into a list
- Save all people into another list
- Serialize all them into a json
- Save to playerpref
  Problem:
- There are so many "people" so the frame-by-frame saving have a big problem: cost too much time to serialize and save to player pref.

Any idea for an auto-save system for this game? Thank you very much?

Comment: wait you need to save all of the people? afaik even cities skyline didn't save them as singular object per se and just spawn relevant cims on the map after the map zoning loaded. sim city back then only lets you save tracked people and its limited in number.

Comment: as each people in my game make structure create profit, so I need tracking as precise as possible

Comment: Probably you will have to choose between performance and precision. Saving 1M objects, even if it's just state, position and role will take same time. Maybe you could divide your game into areas and save how many of each profession are in each square (for eg. square A1 20 doctors, 5 workers)? You could then spawn appropriate number of each on game load. After all, it shouldn't be that important if some random guy moved 50 meters away. Unless it is, then you probably will have to live with long saving times.

Comment: What about not serializing everything into a single JSON file? Sounds like you are looking for some fast database instead where you would also only update those instances that actually changed instead of always saving everything... See e.g. [SQLite](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/code-examples/csharp/saving-data-in-unity3d-using-sqlite/)

Comment: For your people it might e.g. be enough to go event based and only store a new update if they change status or when they start moving to a certain building... I wouldn't store each and every position each frame .. if you need you can still do snapshots as mentioned and only update every XY seconds e.g.